# Using the index for finding a value in a List?

Tags: c#, list

```
List<String> hello = new List<String>();

hello.Add("red");
hello.Add("blue");
```

How do I search this list using the index to get `"red"` which would be `0`? I have tried using a lot of different methods, but failed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, The [`.FindIndex Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)

```
List<String> hello = new List<String>();

hello.Add("red");
hello.Add("blue");

var index = hello.FindIndex(c => c == "red");
var word = hello[index]; //<-- get the word
```

and finally using [`.ElementAt Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx)

```
var word = hello.ElementAt(0);
```

Comment: Better use the list indexer directly. More idiomatic and faster.